# Install Older Ubuntu on 14.04 Machine

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, usb, 10.04

I am in immediate need of installing 10.04 in a laptop that is currently 14.04 (Only Ubuntu). And I have to do this using a USB stick or pendrive only.

I tried using LinuxLiveUSB creator or using instructions at pendrivelinux.com but they generate exe files which don't work in my 14.04 Ubuntu.

I am willing to format my hard disk on my Ubuntu PC and install the 10.04 version. I have a borrowed PC now, so Please help if you could before downvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert your USB drive, run `lsblk`, and note the device location. It will be something like `/dev/sdb`. DO NOT MAKE A MISTAKE HERE.

Run:

```
$ sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/ubuntu-10.04.iso of=/dev/sdx && sync
```

Replace x obviously. This works only for Linux Live USB.

Boot from this drive and install.

Comment: thanks but ib my ubuntu 14.04 i deleted some data and now i can't access the terminal.

Comment: Press Ctrl+Alt+F2. Or Boot into recovery from from GRUB.

Comment: I booted into recovery mode I get a list of options like resume clean ..etc no lsblk

Comment: I got into root shell ran lsblk and get the usb localtion as sdb1

Comment: You only need `/dev/sdb`. Do not use the **1**.

Comment: it says failed to open /dev/sdb ... not a directory

Comment: not working anyhow